# How do you do a ‘Pause’ with PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: powershell

OK, I'm losing it. PowerShell is annoying me. I'd like a pause dialog to appear, and it won't.

```
PS W:\>>> $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
Exception calling "ReadKey" with "1" argument(s): "The method or operation is not implemented."
At line:1 char:23
+ $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey <<<< ("NoEcho")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: I had the same problem in PowerShell ISE. Works fine in the standard PowerShell console though.

Comment: I'm just messing with powershell and it's still annoying as hell, even 2 1/2 years later!

Comment: If you read the [Adam's Tech link](http://adamstech.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/how-to-properly-pause-a-powershell-script/) or the code in [@Michael Sorens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22362868/4582204) (about halfway down the page as I write this in 2020) you may discover a technique of wrapping your pause in `if (!$psise) { <# pause #> }`. If you're like me and 99% of the reason you want a pause is so that you can read the screen before it blinks away, then this will help, because if you're in the ISE it does not blink away and you don't need the pause

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
cmd /c pause | out-null
```

(It is not the PowerShell way, but it's so much more elegant.)

Save trees. Use one-liners.

Comment: /c Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
| out-null   pipes the output to out-null, where you'll never see it

If you want to see the "Press any key to continue..." message, remove the pipe.

Also, this doesn't seem to work in PowerShell ISE. The process simply gets stuck, and you can't press any key. Any way around that?

Comment: @Wouter See this blog post: [How to Properly Pause a PowerShell Script](http://adamstech.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/how-to-properly-pause-a-powershell-script/)

Comment: @Nick yes, 47 lines of code to replace "cmd /c pause | out-null", that sound like the PowerShell way.

Comment: @BillK The post I linked to answers Wouter's question. Do you disagree?

Comment: It wasn't a commentary on your answer, I think you are totally right.  It's a commentary on PowerShell.  I'm moderately disgusted--I haven't seen this much pointless obscuring verbosity since I programmed in Cobol.

Answer (score 280):

I think it is worthwhile to recap/summarize the choices here for clarity... then offer a new variation that I believe provides the best utility.

### <1> ReadKey (System.Console)

```
write-host "Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

- Advantage: Accepts any key but properly excludes Shift, Alt, Ctrl modifier keys.
- Disadvantage: Does not work in PS-ISE.

### <2> ReadKey (RawUI)

```
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

- Disadvantage: Does not work in PS-ISE.
- Disadvantage: Does not exclude modifier keys.

### <3> cmd

```
cmd /c Pause | Out-Null
```

- Disadvantage: Does not work in PS-ISE.
- Disadvantage: Visibly launches new shell/window on first use; not noticeable on subsequent use but still has the overhead

### <4> Read-Host

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
```

- Advantage: Works in PS-ISE.
- Disadvantage: Accepts only Enter key.

### <5> ReadKey composite

This is a composite of <1> above with the ISE workaround/kludge extracted from the proposal on [Adam's Tech Blog](http://adamstech.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/how-to-properly-pause-a-powershell-script/) (courtesy of Nick from earlier comments on this page). I made two slight improvements to the latter: added Test-Path to avoid an error if you use [Set-StrictMode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx) (you do, don't you?!) and the final Write-Host to add a newline after your keystroke to put the prompt in the right place.

```
Function Pause ($Message = "Press any key to continue . . . ") {
    if ((Test-Path variable:psISE) -and $psISE) {
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
        $Button = $Shell.Popup("Click OK to continue.", 0, "Script Paused", 0)
    }
    else {     
        Write-Host -NoNewline $Message
        [void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
        Write-Host
    }
}
```

- Advantage: Accepts any key but properly excludes Shift, Alt, Ctrl modifier keys.
- Advantage: Works in PS-ISE (though only with Enter or mouse click)
- Disadvantage: Not a one-liner!

Comment: Best answer, especially because it provides solution that works everywhere

Comment: Great answer! I'd like to note that adding the `AllowCtrlC` parameter to choice 2 allows the user to click Ctrl + C without terminating the script. Nevertheless, this choice still doesn't properly excludes the Ctrl modifier key. (it acts just as if the user clicks only on the Ctrl key) Reference: [Microsoft TechNet - Windows PowerShell Tip: Press Any Key to Continue](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730938.aspx)

Comment: Option 3 and 5 have another disadvantage: doesn't work on linux

Comment: @bitbonk If you're working in Linux.... why PowerShell? Just why? Use Bash.

Comment: Because I don’t want to maintain multiple scripts, one for each OS. One script for Mac, Linux and Windows should suffice, which is powershell in my case.

Comment: One-liner for <5> option could be: `(New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell").Popup("Click OK to continue.", 0, "Script Paused", 0)`, but it looks somewhat ugly...

Answer (score 46):

I assume that you want to read input from the console. If so, use [`Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347685.aspx).

Comment: Ditto - Maybe add the prompt text pilfered from below.. Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"

Comment: doesn't pause for me for some reason. I'm calling powershell inside a `.bat` script.

Answer (score 22):

The solutions like `cmd /c pause` cause a new command interpreter to start and run in the background. Although acceptable in some cases, this isn't really ideal.

The solutions using `Read-Host` force the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and are not really "any key".

This solution will give you a true "press any key to continue" interface and will not start a new interpreter, which will essentially mimic the original `pause` command.

```
Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

Comment: Technically ISE is out of scope because the original question only asked about Powershell 2.0 and excluded ISE. If you're using ISE, then just use a breakpoint.

Comment: 1. I don't agree ISE was out of scope, but that's irrelevant now. 2. I was noting it doesn't work in the ISE to assist passers-by on this question.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Michael Sorens'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115690/michael-sorens) answer:

### <6> ReadKey in a new process

```
Start-Process PowerShell {[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)} -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

- Advantage: Accepts any key but properly excludes Shift, Alt, Ctrl
  modifier keys.
- Advantage: Works in PS-ISE.

Comment: This works great, but pops up a new window of powershell, unless `-NoNewWindow` has been added :)

Comment: @jeuxjeux20, thanks for the suggestion, I have added this to command in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

10 years later i came here.... Don't know since when, but "pause" works in PowerShell like it did in DOS-commandline.

Comment: Thank you for the update! It answers more than one question I was having, strangely enough.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `FlushInputBuffer` to discard any characters mistakenly typed into the console, especially for long running operations, before using `ReadKey`:

```
Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...'
$Host.UI.RawUI.FlushInputBuffer()
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown') | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a timer to the press any key, this works in PS 5.1:

```
 $i=1
 while (
                 !([Console]::KeyAvailable) -and 
                 ($i -le 10)
            ) {
           sleep 1
           Write-Host “$i..” -NoNewLine
           $i++
 }
```

Note that the KeyAvailable method for the c# $Host.UI.RawUI is currently bugged in a number of PS versions after PS 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

Add just one command:

```
pause
```

[Here is the explanation](https://ss64.com/ps/pause.html)

Answer (score 0):

One-liner for PS-ISE in option <5> in [Michael Sorens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22362868/15394190):

```
[Void][Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Click OK to continue.", "Script Paused")
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as others, EXCEPT this mimicks cmd pause exactly down the line breaks and blinking cursor position

```
Write-Host 'Press any key to continue . . . '-NoNewLine;[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($FALSE);Write-Host
```