# How do I pause PowerShell to see an error?

Tags: powershell

I have tried every recommendation from the link below, but nothing works.

*[How do you do a ‘Pause’ with PowerShell 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963100/how-do-you-do-a-pause-with-powershell-2-0)*

Here is my code:

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select * from TBL_AGG_BOC" -ServerInstance "server_name\SQL2008" -Database "db_name" > "C:\Users\TBL_AGG_BOC.txt"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
```

The script keeps failing, and it shuts down so fast that I can't see what is actually happening. How can I force this to stay open for a few seconds so I can see what is happening here?

The file is saved and named `'test_export.ps1'`, and I right-click the file and then click `'Run with PowerShell'` to fire it off. I don't have administrator rights on this machine. I hope that's not a problem.

Comment: You can also run it with PowerShell ISE

Comment: Type the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command you want to run at a PowerShell prompt and press `Enter`. Read error.

Comment: I added 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' right at the top, saved the file, and re-ran it.  Same thing.  It opens and almost immediately shuts down.  All I am doing is right-clicking this ps1 file and clicking 'Run with PowerShell'.  I think there may be another step that I am missing.

Comment: Slowly reread  and simply follow Bills hint.

Comment: PowerShell ISE would be the quickest solution, `Start-Transcript -Path "C:\transcripts\transcript.txt"` may also help.

Comment: No. Do not right-click the file to run it. (Read my comment carefully and try again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally* I got this working. It was a combination of a few things.

1. Open PowerShell as *Administrator* and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser`
2. Provide `RemoteSigned` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser`
4. Provide `Unrestricted` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This link helped a lot!

*[PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)*

Then, run this:

```
$server = "SERVERNAME\INSTANCE"
$database = "DATABASE_NAME"
$tablequery = "SELECT name from sys.tables"

# Declare connection variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

# Load up the tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the table data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])]"

    # Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "C:\mssql\export\$($Row[0]).csv"

    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

It turned out to be this: `$server = "SERVERNAME"`. Not this: `$server = "SERVERNAME\INSTANCE"`

After I incorporated these changes, everything worked fine.