# Pausing Powershell after Invoke-Sqlcmd

Tags: powershell

First time I've used Invoke-Sqlcmd from Powershell and I've hit an annoying challenge. The script works fine but I need to run it from a shortcut with a "do something to continue" pause after it.
Should be simple? Normally I do a Read-Host "Press enter to continue" but neither that, nor anything else from [How do you do a 'Pause' with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963100/how-do-you-do-a-pause-with-powershell-2-0), works.

The output from the invoke-sqlcmd doesn't hit the screen until after the pause, so disappears instantly.
Almost like it was acting asynchronously.

I've tried endless variations on:

```
Write-Host "Query Result:"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $db3 -Query $qcd -Verbose
Read-Host "Press enter etc..."
```

The only thing I've found that works is to pipe to a loop that iterates through the resulting Datarow object - that just seems overkill

Comment: I really trying to follow you here, but, FYI, Read-ost and Pause is to pause the howel script, not just an interation. Have you already looked at a Do/Until or Do/While for your use case?

Comment: Have you tried putting the invoke into a variable and then calling it?

Comment: @alexzelaya Yes, that works - I can loop through the variable. I guess this has become a bit of a matter of pride :) everything tells me that I should be able to do this - simply emulate the good old pause command that I've used for more than 30 years.

Comment: You can always call cmd via command if you really miss it `cmd /c 'pause'`

Comment: @alexzelaya Doesn't work - it fires before the output from the query is displayed - that's the issue will all the normal methods

Comment: Try getting rid of the `$out =` and assign the variable via cmdlet parameter using `-Variable $out` and the run the cmd pause command.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent more time on this than I'd care to admit to, the best I can come up with is:

```
Write-Host "Query Result:"
$out = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $db3 -Query $qcd -Verbose
Write-Host ($out | Format-Table | Out-String)

Read-Host "Press enter etc..."
```

I feel that's more of a workaround than an answer though

Comment: You can get rid of the `Write-Host` when you output the query.